# iOS: Get Latest Tweet Text Only From Specific User

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, tweets, twitter-fabric

I am wanting to get the latest tweet from a specific user that will not change. So if the specific user was Joe Smith, I would always get the latest tweet from him. I've looked into Fabric which seems to only get specific tweets by ID. The Twitter API looks fairly involved when all I am wanting is the latest tweet from a user. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could achive this by searching for a user and only using th first element

Using from:@tweethandle for example: [from:StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3AStackOverflow&src=typd) and using only the first item!

You can search using TWTRAPIClient's URLRequestWithMethod

Ex: (using SwiftyJSON for parsing JSON) this should print the first tweet

```
let twError:NSErrorPointer = nil
let userID = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID
let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userID)
let request = client.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json", parameters: ["q":"from:StackOverflow","result_type":"recent"], error: twError)


if twError == nil {
    client.sendTwitterRequest(request, completion: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
    let json = JSON(data: data!)
    print(json["statuses"][0])
    })
}
```

More info in the [docs](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/twitter/access-rest-api.html)

Comment: I just got the html at using:https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3AStackOverflow&src=typd. Then I parsed out all of the html code and grabbed the first line with this: <p class=\"TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text\" lang=\"en\" data-aria-label-part=\"0\"> Which works great but will this always work as long as I grab the first one?

Comment: @user1715916 the link provided was just an example of the search you where preforming, and that that search would get you the element you where looking.

Comment: @user1715916 did you try the code out? because parsing html is not easy on swift, it's much easier getting a json and then applying it to your context